# Having issue with printing records

Tags: python, loops, printing

I can't seem to get this to print anything all though if I change the def to "main" it prints fine however when I use the def "readRecords" it doesnt seem to print anything

```
import sys
import from scanner *

def readRecords():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])

    with open(log1, 'r') as f:
        print (f.readline().strip ('\n'))
        for l in f:
            print (l, end="")

    with open(log2, 'r') as f:
        print (f.readline().strip ('\n'))
        for l in f:
            print (l, end="")
```

Comment: `import from scanner *` ?? You need to call the function if you want it to print anything.

Comment: import from scanner * is something for later in the program, I'm just trying to print the records from both logs at this point in the program

Comment: `import from scanner *` is a SyntaxError.

Comment: `readRecords()` is never called in your program, just defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function (and remove the syntax error in your import statement)

```
import sys
from scanner import *

def readRecords():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])

    with open(log1, 'r') as f:
        print (f.readline().strip ('\n'))
        for l in f:
            print(l, end="")

    with open(log2, 'r') as f:
        print (f.readline().strip ('\n'))
        for l in f:
            print(l, end="")

readRecords()
```